# scikit-learn: Multi-label cross validation not working anymore in v0.19

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Dear Stack Overflow users,

I use sklearn to train a multi-label SVM (with probabilities) for text mining. For each entry, I do not have a single target label, but a list. These targets are transformed via a MultiLabelBinarizer:

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer()
x_train = vect.fit_transform(training_texts)

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
training_targets_mlb = mlb.fit_transform(training_targets)

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
clf.fit(x_train, training_targets_mlb)
```

After upgrading sklearn to the latest version 0.19, the above code still works, but the following code for cross validation, which worked in the previous version (0.18 I think), now raises an error:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
cv_scores = cross_val_predict(estimator=clf,
                              X=vect.fit_transform(texts),
                              y=mlb.fit_transform(targets),
                              cv=sklearn.model_selection.KFold(shuffle=True, n_splits=5),
                              method='predict_proba')
```

Error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 647, in cross_val_predict
    y = le.fit_transform(y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py", line 111, in fit_transform
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 583, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (18165, 25)
```

Is this intended behaviour, i.e. am I not supposed to pass an array here? If so, how would I then perform cross validation?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why are doing MultiLabelBinarizer for the target? try to pass the cross_val just targets.

Comment: But it's supposed to cross-validate the same way the initial training is performed, is it not?

Comment: No, its not. `cross_val_predict` will train the `clf` again. Can you add some samples which is causing this error.

Comment: [Thats a bug](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/8773) which is currently being solved. Maybe for next stable release.

Comment: @Paddy is right, just passing the targets works indeed!

Comment: happy to hear :)